# i try to create the interface but running it shows this error i tried to create it again on a new project but it still shows this error someone

Tags: java, android

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.login, PID: 28045
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(178305600bytes) bitmap.
at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19123)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:785)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:643)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:649)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:757)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2980)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2794)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2347)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour and take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and the other links found on that page.

Comment: You haven't provided very much useful information. You need to show us what you are trying to do and where the problem is. In any case, it seems that the error message tells you exactly what is wrong: **"Canvas: trying to draw too large(178305600bytes) bitmap"**

Comment: Ask Question
Give Context
Clarify Context and Question.